# Hooke's law in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a lot of trouble with this problem. I know I know to set up a formula that has all the forces acting on the spring (gravity, force of the spring), but I'm not sure how to write it out.

[image: problem]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The force acting on the brick in vertical direction is

- $Mg-k\cdot s(t)$

with

- $k=\frac{Mg}3$

therefore

$$M\,\ddot s(t)=Mg-\frac{Mg}3\cdot s(t) \implies \ddot s(t)=g-\frac{g}3\cdot s(t)$$

with the initial conditions

- $s(0)=3$
- $\dot s(0)=0$

Comment: I found s(t)=3, but the website I'm using to validate my answers says it's wrong.

Comment: @Alex.G You should find ann equation in time as solution.

Comment: yes, I found s(t)=-3e^(-980t/3)+3 @user, but it says my answer is wrong